# Navigating a Post after creating it with backbone

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, backbone-routing

In a separate view in backbone I have a function that basically creates a new post:

```
save : function(){
    console.log($('#big-input').val());
    console.log(window.id);
    this.collection.create({
        name: $('#big-input').val(),
        adress: $('small-input').val(),
        postedBy: window.id
    });
    //navigate to that post     
},
```

In another view all the views are listed, and if the user clicks one of these views the uri changes to "#post/:id"

and in my roots I have this:

```
routes: {
    "" : "showForm",
    "post/:id" : "showPost"
},


showPost: function(id){

    var curmodel = this.collection.get(id);
    console.log(curmodel);
    var posts = new postView({model:curmodel});
    posts.render();
    $(".maincontainer").html(posts.el);

},
```

I am having no problem to navigate to any of these posts from this list of posts, my router handles them very well, but I am having a problem navigating to the post that I just created after creating possibly inside the `save` function..

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that the new model is being saved to the server before you access it via the route?

To be sure, you can always pass {wait: true} into create() if you'd like to wait for the server before adding the new model to the collection.

example:

```
this.collection.create({
        name: $('#big-input').val(),
        adress: $('small-input').val(),
        postedBy: window.id
    }, {wait:true});
```